# Which encoder and decoder of netty4 should be used?

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I am sending a hex string to a `netty4 socket` of which first 4 bytes represent the length of the actual message.

Tasks that I want to achieve:

1. First Decoder should run a decode the string by reading the length from the first 4 bytes of the incoming hex string and convert the hex string to a string.
2. Then Encoder should run and encode the string coming from decoder to a hex string and append the length of the string at the beginning.

Which `encoder` and `decoder` I should use?

Answer (score 0):

For the conversion from bytes to hex string you can extend the `ByteToMessageDecoder` and implement your decode functionality. To covert from hex string to string you can extend the `MessageToMessageDecoder`

Similarly for encoding you can extend `MessageToMessageEncoder` and `MessageToByteEncoder`

Comment: Okay thank u soo much and I am using MessageToMessageEncoder  for encoding and ByteToMessageDecoder decoder for encoding the order of execution of encoder and decoder is first encoder - > decoder i want this in reverse way first my decoder should get executed and then encoder and I m using DefaultChannelHandlerFactory for this please suggest me how i can make my decoder to execute first

Comment: if you add the decoder and encoder to pipeline, eecoder would execute first on incoming message and encoder would execute on the outgoing message because they are ChannelInbound and Outbound handlers respectively.

Comment: And if i want my decoder should run first and then encoder so which encoder and decoder should i use????

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885638/3599535