# Does ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter and ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter effects the sequence of running encoder and decoder in netty4?

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I am using netty4 to implement encoder and decoder.

When I am extending decoder of type ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter and encoder of type ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter, then what should be its running sequence?

1. First encoder and then decoder.
2. First decoder and then encoder.

Also, how do ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter and ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter effect reading (I/O) and writing (I/O) and where should be used what?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following:

> `ChannelInboundHandler` —Processes inbound data and state changes of all kinds `ChannelOutboundHandler` —Processes outbound data and allows interception of all operations

For example when a message is incoming that is when you are reading data from a socket  the [ChannelInboundHandler](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandler.html) would be notified. Also it would be notified of state changes like writabilityChanged, channelActive and Inactive events.

When you write data to a channel the [ChannelOutboundHandler](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandler.html) would be notified. It also will be notified on calls like connect, disconnect and read made on the channel.

To implement encoders and decoders you can extend predefined decoders and encoders in netty like `ByteToMessageDecoder`, `MessageToMessageDecoder`, `MessageToByteEncoder` and `MessageToMessageEncoder` as it would simplify your tasks.

As for the order of execution of decoders and encoders think of it like this:
When a message reaches your application via the socket it will be in byte streams, then you will have to decode it for processing. When you are sending a message to external parties you will have to encode it into bytes before writing it to the socket. Order of execution of encoders and decoders depend upon this process.

Comment: Suppose I have given input as byte[] to ByteToMessageDecoder It will produce message output. Then It is given as input to the encoder MessageToByteEncoder that will convert message to Byte[]. Can this be a running sequence of Decoder and Encoder?

Comment: Yes, but the message is based on the context. Say in http decoder would produce the request and the encoder would encode the response. Request and Response are different message types.